# Why is this code causing an ArgumentOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#

I'm building an application to transform fractions to percentages. I want it so that if I edit the text in the fraction it refreshes and recalculates the percentage.

When I test it, the first time I edit the fraction it doesn't error and works fine  but the second time I change something in the fraction it errors. I get this error

> An unhandled exception of type System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException occurred in mscorlib.dll

What can I do to fix this?

I'm fairly new to C# so try to dumb it down if at all possible.

**Additional information:** Index and length must refer to a location within the string."

Here's what I have so far:

```
private void fractionNumerator_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || ((e.KeyChar) == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back))))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!((fractionNumerator.Text == "") && (fractionDenominator.Text == "")))
            {
                if ((e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back)))
                {
                    string numer = (fractionNumerator.Text.Substring(0, (fractionNumerator.Text.Length) - 1));
                    string denom = (fractionDenominator.Text);
                    outputPercentage.Text = (((((Convert.ToDouble(numer) / Convert.ToDouble(denom)) * 100).ToString()).Substring(0, 6)) + "%");
                }
                else
                {
                    string numer = ((fractionNumerator.Text) + e.KeyChar.ToString());
                    string denom = (fractionDenominator.Text);
                    outputPercentage.Text = (((Convert.ToDouble(numer)/Convert.ToDouble(denom)*100).ToString()).Substring(0, 6));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void fractionDenominator_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || ((e.KeyChar) == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back))))
        {

            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!((fractionNumerator.Text == "") && (fractionDenominator.Text == "")))
            {
                if ((e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back)))
                {
                    string denom = (fractionDenominator.Text.Substring(0, (fractionDenominator.Text.Length) - 1));
                    string numer = (fractionNumerator.Text);
                    outputPercentage.Text = (((((Convert.ToDouble(numer) / Convert.ToDouble(denom)) * 100).ToString()).Substring(0, 6)) + "%");
                }
                else
                {
                    string denom = ((fractionDenominator.Text) + e.KeyChar.ToString());
                    string numer = (fractionNumerator.Text);
                    outputPercentage.Text = (((Convert.ToDouble(numer) / Convert.ToDouble(denom) * 100).ToString()).Substring(0, 6));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You getting error on which line?

Comment: I'm guessing it's `Substring(0, 6))`, which is somehow being called on a string with less than 6 characters.

Comment: It is one of the `Substring` calls. Stop using Substring to format double outputs. Use a format specifier: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided i can tell that one of your `Substring` methods throws this exception. So its probably has invalid second parameter (its either less than 0 or higher than string length). Check msdn for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

As mentioned in the comments by **mike z**, you should use format strings instead of `Substring` method to format your output. For example `doubleValue.ToString("#.####")` will return 4 digits of fractional part.

Answer (score 0):

Use `yourDoubleExpr.ToString("P4")` to convert from number to percentage string. The multiplication by `100.0` is automatic.

Your problem was that cases like `(3.0 / 4.0).ToString()` lead to a short string, like `"0.75"`, and you cannot take out a `.Substring` of length `6` from that.